# Where is Pip's list of files to remove for a package

Tags: python, pip

Where does pip keep a record of what files to remove when uninstall a package?

I have an application package which is installed from pip, often in editable mode. For convenience after install there are user scripts to add desktop and menu shortcuts. How do I tell pip and other package managers about these extra files so they can be automatically removed when uninstalled?

Typical install scenario:

```
git clone {application}
pip install --editable path\to\myapp-code
python user-scripts\make-menu-shortcuts.py
```

*cross posted to https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-add-to-list-of-files-to-uninstall .*

Comment: i think you don't need to do that, just put package in sitepackage location in your python environment

Comment: @prashantrana the package is already installed in site-packages. I need to add files which aren't in site-packages to the list of files to remove when the package is uninstalled.

Comment: Link is broken (or is private).

Comment: @Perplexabot fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

*draft answer in progress. If you have something better than this, jump in!*

#### Wheel installs

Look for `PYTHONHOME/Lib/site-packages/{package}{version}.dist-info`.
In there is a file called `RECORD`.The Wheel specification has some details on the RECORD format:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#the-dist-info-directory

This directory isn't created for packages installed in editable mode (`pip install --editable path/to/code`).

```
# extract from *.dist-info/RECORD:
../../Scripts/myapp.exe,sha256=tQaANRLxdJ3Su3vLNakbzlNhRtnU-HBhdwHGTpJHTxc,103271
myapp-0.1.20.dist-info/INSTALLER,sha256=zuuue4knoyJ-UwPPXg8fezS7VCrXJQrAP7zeNuwvFQg,4
...
myapp/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc,,
myapp/__pycache__/_version.cpython-36.pyc,,
```

Pip uninstall will remove any files at the paths we add to this file. The hash isn't necessary but take care to append trailing commas if not used.

Windows: it's okay to use native format (`C:\users\...\myapp.lnk`) but files recorded must exist on same drive as dist-info ([ref](https://gist.github.com/maphew/e919c953a5251e70d3e5cba57c75a61d#file-pip-uninstall-error-01-txt)).

```
# myapp.dist-info/RECORD:
myapp-0.1.20.dist-info/INSTALLER,sha256=zuuue4knoyJ-UwPPXg8fezS7VCrXJQrAP7zeNuwvFQg,4
...
myapp/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc,,
myapp/__pycache__/_version.cpython-36.pyc,,
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\myapp.lnk,,
```

```
> pip uninstall myapp
Uninstalling myapp-0.1.20:
  Would remove:
    c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\myapp-0.1.20.dist-info\*
    c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\myapp\*
    c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\test\scripts\myapp.exe
    c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\myapp.lnk
Proceed (y/n)? y
```

---

#### Editable installs

Look in `PYTHONHOME/lib/site-packages` for `myapp.egg-link`. That file contains a path to the code location:

```
D:\code-external\app-code
.
```

In that folder look for `myapp.egg-info`. It has a similar structure to `dist-info` but is not the same.

Running `pip show --files myapp` yields an error:

```
Name: myapp
...
Files:
Cannot locate installed-files.txt
```

Creat `.egg-info/installed-files.txt` and put the extra filename in it. Now `pip show` works, but unfortunately pip uninstall still misses it.

```
> pip show -f myapp
Name: myapp
...
Files:
..\..\test-link.lnk

> pip uninstall myapp
Uninstalling myapp-0.1.20:
  Would remove:
    c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\myapp.egg-link
    c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\test\scripts\myapp-script.py
    c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\test\scripts\myapp.exe
Proceed (y/n)? n
```

---

#### Notes

Figured dist-info/RECORD part out by creating a bare virtual conda environment, noting install time, installing a single small package with pip, and then used Windows Advanced Query Syntax to [search files modified after *timestamp*](https://superuser.com/questions/488251/how-to-search-for-files-modified-after-a-particular-time) locate what was changed within the `envs` folder.

`installed-files.txt`: On Windows the paths must be on same drive as the egg-info folder. `Pip show` always resolves the path as relative, but that's impossible across drives in Windows. You've hit this bug if get the error `ValueError: path is on mount 'C:', start on mount 'D:'`